# Add required Checkbox to a custom button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I want to add "I accept Terms and Conditions" checkbox to my page.

I tried

```
<p><input type="checkbox" required>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" onclick="if(!this.form.checkbox.checked){alert('You must agree to the terms first.');return false}"  />
```

but this type of check box links to this submit button not to the form submit button which i already have on that page. This is the button code to which i want it to be attached

```
<a class="wt-btn wt-post-service" data-id="" data-type="add" href="javascript:;"><?php esc_html_e('Save &amp; Update',); ?></a>
```

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use a type=submit or name=submit the behavior is controlled by the submit button. Just prevent default behavior, check the box, and then either issue alert or submit form.

```js
function warning(){
   event.preventDefault();

   var check = document.getElementById('checkbox');
   var myForm = document.getElementById('myForm');

   if (check.checked==false){
     alert("you must agree to terms and conditions");
   }else{
     myForm.submit();
   }
}
```

```html
<form id='myForm' action="/action_page.php" method = 'POST'>
<p><input id='checkbox' type="checkbox" required>
<input type="button" name='button' value="submit" onclick="warning()"  />
</form>

<a class="wt-btn wt-post-service" data-id="" data-type="add" href="javascript:;"><?php esc_html_e('Save &amp; Update',); ?></a>
Please help.
```

Comment: I want to eliminate

<input type="button" name='button' value="submit" onclick="warning()"  />

and want to use the button which i already have

This one
<a class="wt-btn wt-post-service" data-id="" data-type="add" href="javascript:;"><?php esc_html_e('Save &amp; Update',); ?></a>

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using Javascript/jquery to submit your form. So you need to check if a checkbox is checked or not using Jquery on the button click.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Submit button click
            $('.wt-post-service').click(function(){
    if($(input[type="checkbox"]).is(":not(:checked)")){
                    alert("You must agree to the terms first.");
                }
    });
    });
```

Comment: @DCR I think you missed I have checked it on button code not on document.ready(). Please check the code.

Comment: will this submit the form?

Comment: I want to eliminate

<input type="button" name='button' value="submit" onclick="warning()"  />

and want to use the button which i already have

This one
<a class="wt-btn wt-post-service" data-id="" data-type="add" href="javascript:;"><?php esc_html_e('Save &amp; Update',); ?></a>

Comment: @FaisalKhan This code does exactly the same. On button click (<a class="wt-btn wt-post-service" data-id="" data-type="add" href="javascript:;">) it checks the checkbox and if it is not checked it alerts the user.